# Android specific flavor dependency via Kotlin DSL

Tags: android, gradle-kotlin-dsl, kotlin-dsl

Inside `build.gradle` we could

```
   productFlavors {
        free {
            dimension "tier"
        }
    }
```

Then

```
dependencies { freeDebugImplementation "com.someDependency:free-debug:1.0.0";}
```

BUT when I use `Kotlin DSL`, inside `build.gradle.kts`, I

```
productFlavors { create("free") {...} }
```

Then in `dependencies` I **can not**

```
dependencies { freeImplementation(...)}
```

Error: `^ Unresolved reference: freeImplementation`
So, how can I `implementation` for specific flavor via Kotlin DSL?

Answer (score 22):

I **Kotlin DSL** flavor specific dependency looks like this:

```
dependencies { 
    "freeImplementation"(...)
    "paidImplementation"(...)

}
```

Answer (score 4):

You should use the sample "YOUR_FLAVOR_NAMEimplementation"

```
dependencies {

    "freeImplementation" "your dependency is here"
    "paidImplementation" "your dependency is here"
    // Other dependencies 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
productFlavors {
    free {
            .....
         }
    paid {
            ....
         }
}
```

Write like this in dependencies

```
dependencies {

        freeImplementation "your dependency is here"
        paidImplementation "your dependency is here"
        // Other dependencies    
}
```

Comment: I guess Kotlin DSL might not support `free {...}` to create flavors

Comment: I think this one is helpful https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/feature_variants.html